# Red5, how to get parameters form request in live stream

Tags: red5

Now the client(jwplayer) post request "rtmpt://XXXXX/RtmpRelay/resName", and can play video(RtmpRelay is my red5 project name, and redName is the resource name), but I want the user of client to be verified, That is the client must post userId, like this rtmpt://XXXXX/RtmpRelay/resName?userId=XXX 
  And in my server I use

```
conn.getConnectParams() // conn is a instance of IConnection
```

to get the parameters, it's Ok, but the resource can not be played any more,
I doubt that it took the whole "resName?userId=XXX" as a resource?

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution from this page: https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/6062354-passing-custom-parameters-to-wowza-with-jw-player-6

it taught me using url like this(jwplayer)  : rtmp://stream01.amherst.edu:1935/protected/?token=TESTTOKENmp4:sand_mandala_video.mp4

and I knew from other place that live stream or flv fomat may use flv:, so I use rtmpt://XXXXX/RtmpRelay/?userId=XXXflv:myLiveSteamName,

and everthing goes ok.